# How could I merge 2 documents into one and delete them after this step?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have this model:

```
const person = new Schema({
    name: String,
    lastName: String,
    accounts: [{
            provider: String,
            email: {
                type: String,
                lowercase: true
            }, 
            password: String, 
        }
    ]
})
```

Then a user registered first with Facebook and then with email, now in the database there are two documents. But now I wanna combine these two documents in one and in this way the user could log in to the same "account" but with different types of authentication.

My first option consists of finding each user and then merging, adding to the collection and then deleting the old ones. But I think this could cause problems to long-term

*update *

This is doc 1:

```
   {
    name: "John",
    lastName: "Doe",
    accounts: [{
            provider: "google",
            email: "my@email.com", 
            password: p4ssw0rd, 
    }]
   }
```

This is doc2, ***this doesn't have a name and the last name because these aren't required***:

```
   {
    accounts: [{
            provider: "simple",
            email: "my2@email.com", 
            password: p4ssw0rd2, 
    }]
   }
```

and then the admin can merge and then have this:

```
       {
        name: "John",
        lastName: "Doe",
        accounts: [{
                provider: "google",
                email: "my@email.com", 
                password: p4ssw0rd, 
        },{
                provider: "simple",
                email: "my2@email.com", 
                password: p4ssw0rd2, 
        }]
       }
```

Comment: provide example of doc1 and doc2 and expected output doc3

Comment: @R2D2 I updated the post, Do you have a suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see it as follow:

**Step 1: Update document doc1 with joined content from doc1 and doc2**

```
var doc3=db.collection.aggregate([
{
$match: {
  _id: {
    $in: [
      1,
      2
    ]
   }
  }
 },
 {
  $unwind: "$accounts"
 },
 {
  $group: {
    _id: 1,
    name: {
      $first: "$name"
   },
    lastName: {
      $first: "$lastName"
   },
    accounts: {
      $push: "$accounts"
   }
 }
}
])
db.collection.save(doc3)
```

[playground_step_1](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WTh6RrH__3E)

**Step 2: Remove the doc2 ( _id:2 )**

```
 db.collection.remove({_id:2})
```

It is interesting to understand how you are going to correlate or understand how doc1 is related to doc2 ...

Comment: Thank you!, to be honest, I think the same about how docs are related but apparently, the user(my teacher) will give me a 'request' about which accounts I have to merge at that moment (it's an exercise for my exam), and maybe he registered accounts in this way or maybe with all the fields, that's the 'main' challenge.